# how can I use SwiftEventBus?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I need help. I use SwiftEventbus but when pod installs it installs 5.0.0 not 5.1.0 and I don't have SwiftEventbus working. Any info would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN16U.png)

pod 'SwiftEventBus', :tag => '5.1.0', :git => 'https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus.git'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtbG2.jpg)

Comment: Did you opened the xcworkplace and not the xcodeproj ?